# Hugo can not find created files by node when using concurrently

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, hugo, concurrently

I have a node project which I build with [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) with the following build pipe:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "concurrently -g npm:build:*",
  "build:generate-db": "ts-node ./converter/main.ts",
  "build:tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./static/css/build.css --minify",
  "build:hugo": "hugo --minify",
},
```

- `build`: Call's all commands with prefix `build` in synchron order.
- `build:generate-db`: Create `.md` files for hugo application from a database.
- `build:tailwind`: Generates tailwind file and puts it in correct folder
- `build:hugo`: Creates hugo website with `.md` files and tailwind file.

When I run the script hugo is not finding the `.md` files. When I run the script a second time hugo finds the `.md` files and create the website correct.

What I tried:

- First I thought the problem is the time the file write requires (so hugo is trying to find the files before they got written). This is not the case: Even when I sleep 10 seconds after `build:generate-db` hugo is not able to find the files as well.
- When I run `build:generate-db` and than `build:hugo` it's working.
- The tailwind file is created correctly. (it's also file write so why is this one working?)
- When you run the following config it's working:

```
  "build": "concurrently -g npm:build:* & hugo --minify",
  "build:generate-db": "npm run converter",
  "build:tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./static/css/build.css --minify",
```

The Converter writes like this:

```
writeFileSync(`${resultPath}/${data[titleKey]}.md`, JSON.stringify(resultDto, null, 2))
```

How can I fix this problem?